# Ionic realtime location with Google Maps

Tags: json, node.js, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic3

I doing realtime Google Maps with GPS Json for bus, but I have a error. This error , when location changed create new marker but don' t delete old marker.

```
  showMap() {


var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 14,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.4636383, 30.2679112),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var locations, bus1, bus2, bus3, bus4, bus5, bus6, bus7, bus8, bus9, bus10;
var bus1lat, bus1long, bus2lat, bus2long, bus3lat, bus3long, bus4lat, bus4long, bus5lat, bus5long, bus6lat, bus6long, bus7lat, bus7long, bus8lat, bus8long, bus9lat, bus9long, bus10lat, bus10long = [];
setInterval(()=> {

  this.bus.liveData().subscribe((data) =>{

    bus1lat = data[0].Latitude; bus1long = data[0].Longitude; bus2lat = data[1].Latitude; bus2long = data[1].Longitude; bus3lat = data[2].Latitude; bus3long = data[2].Longitude;
    bus4lat = data[3].Latitude; bus4long = data[3].Longitude; bus5lat = data[4].Latitude; bus5long = data[4].Longitude; bus6lat= data[5].Latitude; bus6long = data[5].Longitude;
    bus7lat = data[6].Latitude; bus7long = data[6].Longitude; bus8lat = data[7].Latitude; bus8long = data[7].Longitude; bus9lat = data[8].Latitude; bus9long = data[8].Longitude;
    bus10lat = data[9].Latitude; bus10long = data[9].Longitude;

    bus1 = {
      info: '<strong> Servis 1 </strong><br>\
      Bu servis servis 1 dir ',
      lat : bus1lat,
      long: bus1long
    };
    bus2 = {
      info: '<strong> Servis 2 </strong><br>\
      Bu servis servis2 dir',
      lat : bus2lat,
      long: bus2long
    };
    bus3 = {
      info: '<strong> Servis 3 </strong><br>\
      Bu servis servis3 dir',
      lat : bus3lat,
      long: bus3long
    };
    bus4 = {
      info: '<strong> Servis 4 </strong><br>\
      Bu servis servis4 dir',
      lat : bus4lat,
      long: bus4long
    };
    bus5 = {
      info: '<strong> Servis 5 </strong><br>\
      Bu servis servis5 dir',
      lat : bus5lat,
      long: bus5long
    };
    bus6 = {
      info: '<strong> Servis 6 </strong><br>\
      Bu servis servis6 dir',
      lat : bus6lat,
      long: bus6long
    };
    bus7 = {
      info: '<strong> Servis 7 </strong><br>\
      Bu servis servis7 dir',
      lat : bus7lat,
      long: bus7long
    };
    bus8 = {
      info: '<strong> Servis 8 </strong><br>\
      Bu servis servis8 dir',
      lat : bus8lat,
      long: bus8long
    };
    bus9 = {
      info: '<strong> Servis 9 </strong><br>\
      Bu servis servis9 dir',
      lat : bus9lat,
      long: bus9long
    };
    bus10 = {
      info: '<strong> Servis 10 </strong><br>\
      Bu servis servis10 dir',
      lat : bus10lat,
      long: bus10long
    };

    locations = [
      [bus1.info, bus1.lat, bus1.long, 0],
      [bus2.info, bus2.lat, bus2.long, 1],
      [bus3.info, bus3.lat, bus3.long, 2],
      [bus4.info, bus4.lat, bus4.long, 3],
      [bus5.info, bus5.lat, bus5.long, 4],
      [bus6.info, bus6.lat, bus6.long, 5],
      [bus7.info, bus7.lat, bus7.long, 6],
      [bus8.info, bus8.lat, bus8.long, 7],
      [bus9.info, bus9.lat, bus9.long, 8],
      [bus10.info, bus10.lat, bus10.long],
    ];
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++){
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
        return function () {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }

      })(marker, i));
    } // for

  }); // subscribe
}, 5000);
}//ShowMap
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFyIA.png)

10 pointers that should be, but the json data changes every time create new markes and don' t delete old makers. Can you help me? I want to show realtime locations just 10 markes.